# Google Chrome css translate3d/scale3d rendering bug (with big divs)

Tags: css, google-chrome, bug-reporting

Google Chrome ver: 32.0.1700.76 m
OS: win7

Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/Hh56v/

Zoom-out a yellow box with mouse scroll and then pan the box. Watch the result.

note: happens when div is reasonably big.

```
function createLargeBlock() {
    layer.innerHTML = '<div style="width: 6400px; height: 3600px;" class="large-block"></div>';   
}
```

note2: in a few previous major versions this worked well.

Comment: Reproduced 32.0.1700.76m on Windows 7...the yellow box turns to gray, doesn't repaint, and even draws on top of the jsfiddle frame borders.

Comment: Tim, thanks for reproducing.